# 1890s birth for Anna Hunkalo in Lwów?

Tags: birth-records, poland, 1890s, ukraine

I am trying to find information on the birth family of Anna Hunkalo, born 21 March, 1890/1897. Official records for her a few. Her country of origin is different on all of them, including her children's birth certificates, her marriage record, and the 1921 Canadian census.

What I do know: she immigrated to Winnipeg, Canada by 1915, as her eldest son was born there in December of that year. She was likely ethnically Polish, and Catholic. She died in Vancouver in 1987. Her death certificate

[image] lists her parents as John and Anna Hankark, both from Posen, Austria. However, a note in family papers states their names as Mehanio Hunkalo and Maria Perdun. A note in her handwriting lists her hometown as Wiesh Zaluza, Jawovow.

[image] [image]

I've searched for her and her parents in the Galicia database and JewishGen, with no luck.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to locate her possible birth record?

Comment: First, you should rewrite your questions so that it is clearer. It all sounds very confusing to me (not English native). You should if possible provide scans of documents about known information of those people. Also, Posen was in Germany, not Austria. Then, the name "Jawovow" and "Zaworovo" are suspect - either it's spelled in Polish and only W exists but no V, either it's spelled in another slavic language and it's the exact opposite. You can't have W and V in the same name in this region. *Wiesh* to me sounds like a slavic word meaning "village".

Comment: @Bregalad - I've edited the question and added the notes referred to in the text. I hope that it is more clear now. In the question, I wrote the place names exactly how they are written in death cert. and notes- I did not want to add any potential bias.

Comment: I've looked for other places being called "Posen" or "Poznan" than the famous large city. Two villages are called like that in eastern Poland and western Ukraine, but both were in the Russian Poland pre-1914. So the only place left I found that *could* be in Austria before is [this hamlet](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/3009742000#map=13/49.9656/19.0563). I'm not *quite* sure because it's very near the 1914 German/Austrian border; I am not sure on which side it is. Pszczyna directly on the west was definitely German and Breszcze directly on the east was definitely Austrian.

Comment: Well let's forget it, this was on the german side (Vistula being the former border) and the place didn't even exist back then.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Bregalad. I suspect that the information on the DC is incorrect. She was likely raised in the Austro-Hungarian empire, as she remembered singing songs to Franz Joseph as a child at school. But this family had always been secretive about Anna's country of birth. I suspect this may be because of the sentiment towards people from that region,  when she was a new immigrant to Canada:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Canadian_internment